# How can I get the actual URL being accessed in a compiled Meteor app?

Tags: javascript, cordova, meteor

I'm using a helper with `return document.URL`, but it's [giving a localhost url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYxxL.png), which is presumably due to Cordova.

I want to see something like `https://my.domain.com/pa/th`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More details to make Tdm's answer complete

```
Meteor.absoluteUrl(_.trimStart(location.pathname, '/'))
```

This will return a full url including the correct domain and current path.

**References**

- [Meteor.absoluteUrl](http://docs.meteor.com/api/core.html#Meteor-absoluteUrl)
- [location.pathname](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_pathname.asp)
- [Lodash _.trimStart](https://lodash.com/docs#trimStart)

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need `Meteor.absoluteUrl()`([docs](http://docs.meteor.com/api/core.html#Meteor-absoluteUrl))